# Using FillPath to create a polygon with holes

Tags: c#, geometry, drawing, draw, gdi+

I have the following code:

```
using (var gp = new GraphicsPath())
{    
    var outer = new PointF[outerpoly.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < outerpoly.Count; i++)
    {
        outer[i] = new PointF(((int)(scale * outerpoly[i].X - xmin)), (int)(scale * (outerpoly[i].Y + -ymin)));
    }
    gp.AddPolygon(outer);
    foreach (var hole in insideholes)
    {
        if (hole.Count < 3) continue;
        var inner = new PointF[hole.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < hole.Count; i++)
        {
            inner[i] = new PointF(((int)(scale * hole[i].X - xmin)), (int)(scale * (hole[i].Y + -ymin)));
        }
        gp.AddPolygon(inner);
    }
    Graphics.FromImage(e).FillPath(color, gp);
}
```

where outerpoly is a list of intpoints (pairs of `x` and `y`) representing the outer border of the polygon and inside holes are a list of list of intpoints representing the holes in side the polygon.

Now this code should draw a polygon with a number of holes in it. A example of what the inner and outer might be given as values:

```
outer
{System.Drawing.PointF[4]}
    [0]: {X=-289, Y=971}
    [1]: {X=-289, Y=0}
    [2]: {X=734, Y=971}
    [3]: {X=-289, Y=971}
inner
{System.Drawing.PointF[4]}
    [0]: {X=-158, Y=797}
    [1]: {X=189, Y=568}
    [2]: {X=-158, Y=568}
    [3]: {X=-158, Y=797}
```

Now the result of this code is that only the outer is drawn and the holes are ignored. Any idea why?

The code is based on the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021078/drawing-polygon-with-more-than-one-hole).

When trying to use the exclude method instead like in the following:

```
var outer = new PointF[outerpoly.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < outerpoly.Count; i++)
{
    outer[i] = new PointF(((int)(scale * outerpoly[i].X - xmin)), (int)(scale * (outerpoly[i].Y + -ymin)));
}
var gp = new GraphicsPath();
gp.AddPolygon(outer);
Region rr = new Region(gp);

foreach (var hole in insideholes)
{
    if (hole.Count < 3) continue;
    var inner = new PointF[hole.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < hole.Count; i++;)
    {
        inner[i] = new PointF(((int)(scale * hole[i].X - xmin)), (int)(scale * (hole[i].Y + -ymin)));
    }
    var gpe = new GraphicsPath();
    gpe.AddPolygon(inner);
    Region.Exclude(gpe);
    gpe.Dispose();
}
gp.Dispose();

Graphics.FromImage(e).FillRegion(color, rr);
rr.Dispose();
```

This crashed on the line `Region.Exclude(gpe);` instead, no exception, just a sudden crash to desktop.

Comment: Sounds like a dupe of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15078609/1997232)  (note: vb.net). Try using `StartFigure`.

Comment: That question deals with visual basic not c#. How would I translate that?

Comment: This is why I am not voting to close it. Try accepted answer from there. If it works for you then post answer for future `C#`-**only** programmers.

Comment: I'm also basing myself on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021078/drawing-polygon-with-more-than-one-hole , so I was hoping that I could find out what I was doing wrong compared to that (my vb is really bad)

Comment: Try [excluding polygons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbatwtk(v=vs.110).aspx) (holes) instead of adding them.

Comment: I have also added my attempt at using exclude region, this resulted in a crash on the line         Region.Exclude(gpe);

Comment: Was a bad idea. Maybe you simply have to set proper `FillRule`, see [this](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFPolygon.aspx).

Comment: A graphicsPath only has a FillMode not a FillRulle (which when I set it to Alternate didn't change anything). Or do you mean in somewhere else?

Comment: More like [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.fillmode(v=vs.110).aspx). Sorry for mixing up with wpf. It would be easier if you prepare [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for someone else being able to: 1) reproduce the problem 2) try something to fix it.

Comment: You started a bounty for this question. Currently no answer will automatically be awarded the bounty (as all are < 2 votes). Is there anything missing in these answers that you still want to know?

Comment: No just hadn't checked that you were correct yet. I rewarded your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried your code by using it in the `Paint` event and drawing on my `Form` (using the `Graphics` from the `PaintEventArgs`).
You're `Exclude` attempt actually works fine. I think your problem arises in this line:

```
Region.Exclude(gpe);
```

The reason being, you actually mean

```
rr.Exclude(gpe);
```

You want to exclude the `GraphicsPath` from your `rr`, which you will fill later.
By typing `Region` you are probably **cutting the region of the `Control`**. `Region` is a property of a `Control`, not the instance you wanted to draw to.
If you declared this method inside your main `Form` this would explain why you encounter a *"just a sudden crash to desktop"*, since you are destroying your `Form`'s drawing region.

Answer (score 3):

I generally join all inner graphics before and I create a GraphicsPath with the both outer and inner.
The default fill mode does the holes.

I use clipper to join the polygons:
http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php

If you need to clip the outer, you should create a clipping region:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/155t36zz(v=vs.110).aspx

```
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        var path = new GraphicsPath();

        Rectangle outer = new Rectangle(100, 100, 300, 300);
        Rectangle inner = new Rectangle(150, 150, 200, 200);

        path.AddRectangle(outer);
        path.AddRectangle(inner);

        var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
        g.FillPath(brush, path);
```

[image: Hole]